# Why does requireSSL true still send the cookies over HTTP?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, webforms

I'm trying to wrap my head around the secure flag on my applications cookies, in tandem with my different deployment environments and I'm hoping someone can help clarify.

#### My Application

A .NET 4.7.2 Web Forms application using Forms authentication.  The login page sets 5 cookies in code, including the Auth token cookie.

#### What I'm seeing with the secure flag

On my local, non-https development environment running IIS Express, when I set `requireSSL` to true on the `httpcookies` element in the web.config.  I can see in the browser that the secure flag is set on all the cookies (including the auth token cookie), but the app seems to work fine.

That already doesn't make sense to me because I thought the flag would tell my browser not to send those cookies...

If I set `requireSSL` on the `forms` element, then it seems to do what I would expect, it seems to prevent me from logging in because I'm on a dev non-https environment.

Does anyone know why this is?  Why don't they both behave the same way?